# A faster way to move photos from one event to another existing event in iPhoto?

Tags: photos, photos.app

When I drink a beer I enjoy I like to snap a photo of it with my iPhone. I keep an event in iPhoto called **Beer** and in to this event go all those photos I snap.

Over time the **Beer** event has started to get lost among all my other iPhoto events. The ones of the kids and wife, the relatives, the sunsets I'll never remember to look at again. So when I have a new picture of some beer I enjoyed to add to the all-important **Beer** event, finding that event and dragging the handful of photos in to it has gotten to be tedious.

I do try to keep the **Beer** event at the end of my event list. So it's nearest newly added events when I import photos from my phone. But that doesn't always work out and, of course, I'd rather not have to remember to reorder **Beer** to the end of my event list every single time I import photos.

I've tried cutting and pasting after import. But that still seems to require that find the Beer event by scrolling up and down through the Event view in iPhoto. Not something I enjoy.

I can use the search box to search for "beer" and I do see the photos from that event, but I can't do anything meaningful with the search results like paste a lone phone in to the found event named **Beer**. The way the search results are listed is really as individual photos. I don't see a way to limit the search to events by names that I can then click down in to like I normally would in the Event view.

I feel like I'm missing some fundamentally easy way to shuffle photos between random events in iPhoto. A click and 'move to event' type deal that would whisk away my favourite beverage photos to their safe home in my electronic memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps doesn't directly answer your question, but sounds like you ought to consider creating a Beer album, rather than using a Beer event.

iPhoto Events are really designed for arranging temporally-related photos, i.e. photos that were taken in a similar time period. Albums are better for storing contextually-related photos, i.e. photos of the same thing over any period of time.

Albums work like iTunes playlists, in that the same photo can appear in multiple albums, or in no albums at all. (But it has to appear in exactly one event.) Albums are always visible in your sidebar, so you can easily drag photos from any event (including your "Latest Import" event, for example) into any album at any time.

All that said, somebody here could probably quickly whip up a little AppleScript for you that automates your current process. But not me :)

Comment: this is *exactly* the answer I needed. Albums were my missing bit of tech in iPhoto -- I wasn't using them. And the temporal restrictions of Events was exactly what I was grappling with in iPhoto. Perfect solution to my problem. Thanks!

Comment: A late thank you for this...  I keep various pictures of exotic cars in iPhoto and have been wanting to group them all together.  I lost the distinction between events and albums somewhere along the way- been using iPhoto since 2004